# CSV File displayed by browser insteed of prompting download

Tags: php, ajax, csv, download, httpd.conf

In my application, it returns a csv file location on my server through an ajax call of a php page.
I want the browser to prompt for download. I use

```
location.href = "report.csv";
```

But when the code is executed in a browser, it opens the csv file by itself and is not prompting for download.

This problem occurs with my LAMP server whereas in my laptop, which is configured in XAMPP, the same code works fine and prompts for download.

I have found that some programmer refer to use content-dispose as header in the page.
But I think I have missed some configuration in httpd.conf file.

Does anyone have the solution?

Thanks in advance.

Tathagata

Answer (score 1):

set `location.href = a.php` (as example). then set header content of that a.php file to csv type and then echo your csv file(see google help). Maybe this will help you. see header content for csv file for html page from google.

Comment: `<?php header('Content-type:text/csv'); ?>` if you're unsure : http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt

Comment: Is their any way to configure httpd.conf for prompting download for any csv file requested?? 

header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");

Can content-Disposition configured in httpd.conf?